# disabling ipv6 on windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, ipv6

not sure what i am missing here..

every website suggests creating this reg key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\DisabledComponents

as DWORD and setting its value to 0xFFFFFFFF

i've done this, but when i reboot, my NIC adapter still shows IPV6 enabled.

since i have 64bit version, i also tried setting this value as QWORD. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because it's turned off in registry doesn't mean your check box on NIC will dissapear. It just means it's disabled. Just to be sure I usually do it in both places (in registry and NIC properties). For Windows 7 however doing it on NIC properties should be enough, but for Exchange 2010 (as a side note) it brings Windows Server to knees.

Couple of ways to disable IPv6 completely (just for answer completeness):

- Run this from command prompt `reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\tcpip6\parameters /v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 255` and then reboot.
- Run this Microsoft **Fixit** utility http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852

Some helpful links:

- http://windows7themes.net/disable-ipv6-windows-7.html
- http://www.techjunoon.com/how-to-properly-disable-ipv6-in-windows-7/

Comment: ok, how can i verify my registry change worked? and should i be using DWORD in 64bit windows?

Comment: Running this from prompt should do it:  `reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\tcpip6\parameters /v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 255` but it's exactly as you already did it. You could verify it with `ipconfig /all` in `cmd` window.

Comment: ipconfig -all doesn't say anything about ipv6.. also should be using DWORD (32bit) value in 64bit windows? or QWORD ?

Comment: http://windows7themes.net/disable-ipv6-windows-7.html here's a good link to get you thru. When i did ipconfig /all on my machine it shows: `Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4c50:ae33:88df:5fae%12`, 
`IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.29`

Comment: Try the Microsoft "Fixit" utility...you need to reboot after you make the registry change...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852

Comment: See the "applies to" section of that MS link I posted, DWORD 32bit applies to 64bit versions also.